# Find the length of common chord of two intersecting circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Let us consider two intersection circles

$x^2+y^2+2g_1x+2f_1y+c_1=0$

and  $x^2+y^2+2g_2x+2f_2y+c=0$.
Then equation of common chord of the above two circles is
\begin{equation}2(g_1-g_2)x+2(f_1-f_2)y+c_1-c_2=0............(1)
\end{equation}
I want to find the length of the chord (1).
Any one help me to find out the length of chord.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find centers $C_1$ and $C_2$ of the two circles and their radii $r_1$ and $r_2$. An intersection point $X$ makes a triangle $\triangle C_1C_2X$ with sides $|C_1C_2|$, $r_1$ and $r_2$, so its area can be easily obtained with the [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). When you divide the area by the base length $|C_1C_2|$, you'll get a half of the triangle's height – and that is a fourth part of the chord's length you're seeking.

**Edited** – added $1/2$ coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Equation is unnecessary. The length is given by $2\sqrt{(C_1P)^2-(C_1M)^2}$ where $C_1P$ is radius of circle 1 and $C_1M$ is length of perpendicular from $C_1$ to common chord $PQ$ can you take it from there.

Comment: @A.W. would you tell me how can I find $C_1M$?

Comment: Why -1??? Whats wrong

Comment: Take a triangle and join ends where c1 and c2 intersects so wont the c1m be the height??

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you want to use the equation of the line $2(g_1-g_2)x+2(f_1-f_2)y+c_1-c_2=0$, intersects this line with a circle (i.e. solve the system of the two equations), so you find the two common points of the two circles, than take the distance form these.